# Earliest known proof of "Any degree one self-map of an orientable connected finite-type non-compact surface is homotopic to a homeomorphism"

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

I attended a talk where the speaker said the following is due to Nielsen. I searched here and there but couldn't find the corresponding paper, if any. So, *what is the earliest known proof of the following fact?* I am looking for a reference, not proof.

> Theorem: Any degree one **self-map** of an orientable connected
> **finite-type non-compact** surface is homotopic to a homeomorphism.

Note that any orientable connected finite-type non-compact surface is obtained from deleting finitely many points from a closed orientable connected surface of the genus $g$.